# console.log() is not working when I use postman

Tags: javascript, jwt, console.log

I have this function that I was trying to debug because i was getting an error.  I have since fixed the issue because I found someone with a similar problem, but being able to console log one of the parameters in the JwtStrategy would have really helped and given me a better understanding what was being passed through.  I still can't seem to console it even though others have been able to using Postman and their source code.

So I have mongod and nodemon running in the back.  and I this is the function.

```
module.exports = function(passport){

    let opts = {}; //options is an object literal containing options to control how token is extracted.
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt")  
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret; //string containing the secret or pem encoded public key verifying the tokens signiture
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload,done)=>{
        console.log(jwt_payload);  
        User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id, (err, user)=>{  
            if(err){
                return done(err,false);
            }
            if(user){
                return done(null, user);
            }else{
                return done(null,done);
            }
        });
    }));
}
```

As you see, I have a console.log(jwt_payload);
This is what I put into Postman
Post method, http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate, body:

```
{
    "username":"bobdylan",
    "password":"123456"
}
```

As I said above it is working and returning the correct JSON that I want.  The only problem is that this jwt_payload isn't console logging in the terminal so I can see it passing through.  I have this in the terminal.

```
Server started on port 3000
yay i am connected to databasemongodb://localhost:27017/authapp
```

So the "yay I am connected" is a console.log in the app.js.  Why is this printing but not my console.log above?  I would like to have this ability for future debugging issues.

This is additional code showing that it is actually working but the console log isnt working

```
{
    "sucess": true,
    "token": "JWTeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YTk2M2VmMGM3MjM4NjA0MGUwYTgwZjEiLCJuYW1lIjoiYm9iIiwiZW1haWwiOiJib2JAZHlsYW4uY29tIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJib2JkeWxhbiIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiJDJhJDEwJHprbFBVWjI5dlJMLjRJWnlOZ1N6amVaMk1mVGVzcWdRSHIuTEkzVjhmZTIwT1NxT2p0STdLIiwiX192IjowLCJpYXQiOjE1MTk3OTk0NTcsImV4cCI6MTUyMDM5OTQ1N30.DlwzJuQayQ1zc4p8Gy5PGaE22N8ekyrBrmOhVPMkJ6Y",
    "user": {
        "id": "5a963ef0c72386040e0a80f1",
        "name": "bob",
        "username": "bobdylan",
        "email": "bob@dylan.com"
    }
}
```

So that is the response after the request.

Comment: So what happens if you `console.log('this is a test')` at the same location?

Comment: I tried a string as well and it doesn't show up.

Comment: And `User.getUserById(...)` works correctly? If so, that is very perplexing.

Comment: Ya, it all worked and response was 200 and the body was success true with the token and user object being sent.  I don't get it.

Comment: I can add more code above showing that the req res truly is working, but the consolelog not working

Comment: Please scroll down, after more work and research, it's still not working

Answer (score 12):

For anyone who is struggling with output of `console.log`, `console.info`, etc in `Postman`

You can view postman console on menu `View >> Show Postman Console`

not on menu View >> Developer >> Show DevTools

[image: Open Postman Console to see output of console.log, console.info, etc.]

Answer (score 0):

changed user.toJSON() to {data:user}. Finally it started printing to the console and found out the payload was coming in through an object called data. Because of this I put jwt_payload.data._id instead of what I had above. I think the npm documentation has changed with updates. I have another Mean app using passport and I used jwt_payload._doc._id which worked before. Also I don't think I had to put {data:user}. I think before I just had user there. Im surprised the registration and authentication worked with user.toJSON() but didn't work with going to the profile page. I really was about to give up but thankfully I tried again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Change `opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt")` to
`opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT')`

JWT in capitals